# How to change a value between 2 words with IF() in Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to change a value between on / off in a table using this code:

```
$sql = "UPDATE example SET IF(status = 'on','off','on') WHERE id = '16'";
$connect->exec($sql);
```

But it is not working correct and I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF(statuss = 'on','off','on') WHERE id = '16'' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the assignment to the field name.

Try with this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE example SET status = IF(status = 'on','off','on') WHERE id = '16'";
$connect->exec($sql);
```